# Fire off script with return key

Tags: javascript, calculator

I want to get this calculator to do the equation just by the press of the return key while the textbox is selected
Here is my Script:

```
var D = "";
var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
var C = document.getElementById("num2").value;

D = eval(A + B + C);


document.getElementById("result").value = D;
}
```

Here is one of the text boxes:

```
<table align="center"><td>(Number 1)<input type="text" id="num1" align="middle" name="num1" />
</td>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: onkeypress... I had false hope... When I search I only find key codes

Comment: You don't need the eval and when getting text from a text box you and use it as a number you should convert it to a number: var A = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value,10); //use parseFloat for numbers with decimal values...document.getElementById("result").value =A+B+C

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your inputs in a form:

```
<form onsubmit="return calculateFunction()">
<!-- your html-->
</form>
```

Then your calculate funciton:

```
function calculateFunction(){
// your code
 return false;
}
```